# guildmemberupdate event only occurs when bot gets updated

Tags: events, discord.js

This only picks up when the actual bot gets updated and not when other users update

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate' ,(oldMember,newMember) => {
    console.log(oldMember['_roles'])
    console.log(newMember['_roles'])
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html

Read through this page - You need to use intents when connecting to the gateway

so

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: Discord.Intents.ALL } })
```

And enable intents on your application's Page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4t9.png) enable both.